# Intercepting 'blur' event on last focusable element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, accessibility

I'm working on a modal component to be used across my organisation's website and digital services (around 17,000 pages created over the last 15+ years with millions of monthly users). As you can imagine these pages vary considerably and it's impossible to test them all.

To maximise the accessibility of this component I need to **restrict focus (via the tab key and/or virtual cursor) to the modal while the modal is open**.

My approach has been to attach a handler to the `blur` event on the last focusable element that returns focus to the first focusable element in the modal. This works absolutely fine **unless the last focusable element in the modal is also the last focusable element on the page**, in which case focus returns to the browser search bar.

I've been pretty puzzled by this for a couple of days and unable to find any information to indicate why this would be. Here's some simplified code which illustrates the issue:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Focus trap</title>
        <style>button:focus {background-color: orange;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="modal">
        <button id="link-1">Link-1</button>
        <button id="link-2">Link-2</button>
        <button id="link-3">Link-3</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        let last_link = document.getElementById('link-3'),
            first_link = document.getElementById('link-1');

        last_link.addEventListener('blur', () => {
            first_link.focus();
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm aware of a few things we could do, but none of these are ideal:

- Try intercepting keyboard events rather than `blur` - but I'm reluctant to do that because it's likely to exclude users of some assistive technologies
- Create and hide an additional focusable element in the modal - which I'm reluctant to do because it feels a bit of a hack

Answer (score 1):

You can't go against the address bar or native toolbars being focused. They take the priority over whatever you could say and there are fortunately very good reasons for that to be so.

The solution is one of the two options you have already mentionned:

- Intercept tab on the last element, as well as shift+tab on the first one
- Put two hidden focusable elements, one at the beginning and one at the end, and move the focus to the first or last element as soon as your hidden focusable elements get focus.

I don't see which assistive technology would be defeated by doing tab/shift+tab interception. If you think about touch interface, anyway iOS/Android work completely differently with focus.
If you think about special devices, many of them simulate pressing keys on the keyboard, independently of the effective way their actions are triggered.

In case of doubt, the second one looks more like an hack, but is more robust if there effectively exist a special way to move the focus other than by the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: If I capture tab and shift+tab, is it okay to assume that users needing keyboard access can guess that Escape key can be used to exit the capture? Should there be explicit focusable element to exit the loop?

Comment: Yes, there should ideally always be a close / back / cancel button to go out of the loop. 
It's acceptable to don't have any in case the loop is quite short-lived, for example for a menu, as escape is quite well known among keyboard users. It's much less acceptable for a dialog  with input fields because in this case, one may not think to press escape or escape may have another function (example: cancel current input without leaving the dialog), though.